# function for counting number of oscillations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, asammdf

i'm trying to build a counter which would detect number of oscillations in a given data
i'm following a method where the slope of each point is calculated and based on negative and positive direction change
is there a preexisting function for this
i'm using the following code and i'm unable to leave out the cells with zero values after taking difference between each cell

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from asammdf import MDF
import numpy as np
dat = MDF("file_name.dat")
app = dat.get('variabe_name')
df = pd.DataFrame(app)
print(df)
data = df.loc[0, 0:]
#time step = T
T = 0.01
# Number of sample points
N = len(data)
# sample spacing
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)
x1 = data.diff()
print(x1)
df1_1 = pd.DataFrame([x1])
df1_1 = df1_1.replace(0, np.nan)
df1_1 = df1_1.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
df1_1 = df1_1.dropna()
df1 = pd.DataFrame.transpose(df1_1)
df1.to_csv("output.csv")'
```

my data looks like this

Comment: looks like a job for [scipy.signal.find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset (such as the file_name.dat file)?

Comment: filename : app_measured, variable : app